# Wrapping variable width text in Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am hacking up a tagging application for emacs.  I have got a tag cloud/weighted list successfully displaying on a buffer, but i am running into a snag.  I need to be able to properly word-wrap the buffer, but I haven't a clue where to start.

The font I am using is a variable width font.  On top of that, each tag is going to be in a different size, depending on how many times it shows up on the buffer.  Finally, the window that displays the tagcloud could be in a window that is 200 pixels wide, or the full screen width.

I really have no idea where to start.  I tried longlines mode on the tagcloud buffer, but that didn't work.

Source code is at: http://emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/emacs/free-tagging.el

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to track [`posn-at-point`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Accessing-Events.html#index-posn_002dat_002dpoint-1273) and [`posn-at-x-y`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Accessing-Events.html#index-posn_002dat_002dx_002dy-1274) as you put the tags in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `(fill-paragraph)` or `(fill-region)` or similar? They wrap at a column, so don't have variable width font smarts, but if the fill column is low they might work for next to no effort. At least until you get a pixel-perfect solution sorted out :-) (maybe YAGNI...)

Comment: That didn't seem to work at all actually.  Thanks for the suggestion though.